# Do EM waves have negative frequency inside negative-index materials?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, metamaterials

The speed of light in a vacuum, $c$, is defined as positive.

The refractive index of a material, $n$, can be positive or negative.

The dispersion relation for light inside the material is given by

$$\omega=\frac{c}{n}|\mathbf{k}|.$$

The magnitude of the wavevector, $|\mathbf{k}|$, must be positive by definition therefore the sign of the wave frequency $\omega$ is determined solely by the refractive index $n$.

Thus if the refractive index $n$ is negative then the frequency $\omega$ is negative.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769824/2451