# Left-handed antiphotons in negative-index material?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, antimatter, metamaterials

Do “left-handed” antiphotons propagate in negative-index metamaterials?

https://pubs.aip.org/physicstoday/article/57/6/37/914849/Reversing-Light-With-Negative-RefractionMaterials

Some quotes from the above paper by John B. Pendry and David R. Smith:

> Veselago always referred to the materials as “left handed,” because
> the wave vector is antiparallel to the usual right-handed cross
> product of the electric and magnetic fields.

> One can see why materials with negative n are so special: Negative
> media behave like optical antimatter.

A previous [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/769969/do-em-waves-have-negative-frequency-inside-negative-index-materials) argues that photons in negative-index metamaterials have negative energy/frequency and therefore are antiphotons in the [Feynman-Stueckelberg interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparticle#Feynman%E2%80%93Stueckelberg_interpretation) of antimatter.

When viewed with time going forward the antiphoton has a wave vector that is antiparallel to its [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector). As it propagates through a negative-index medium its phase decreases instead of increasing like a normal photon propagating through a positive-index medium.